# Set the page width to max 970px within Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to build a website that displays nicely on mobile devices and desktops. The customer tells me that the max width of a page can only be 970px.

How can I do this with Bootstrap 3 to make sure that:

1. The page still centered in a browser screen?
2. All the great things in Bootstrap 3 are still there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap actually have a less feature on their website. [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) you can pick and choose what components of bootstrap you want to use. All of bootstrap is made to be responsive so you can change the size to be whatever you want and everything will inherit from that.

So if you want to define .container as max-width: 970px that might serve your purposes. Or maybe just change the media query breakpoints.

Edit: Just took a look and you can define the size of your grid system for each screen size in the customize section. @container-sm, @container-md, @container-lg

Second Edit: [I forgot about this resource I had bookmarked from a while back. You will probably find it useful](http://bootswatchr.com/)

Comment: "define .container as max-width: 970px that might serve your purposes" --- doesn't this involve changes in other places? --- "Or maybe just change the media query breakpoints." --- can you please provide concrete examples? I know what media query is and know how to write.

Comment: Do you want your container to be different sizes depending on the device being used? You can define the max width of your media queries, and then the container-lg, container-md, container-sm will corespond to those media queries. So if you want to have a slightly modified version of the bootstrap css files just fill in the form on that page as you like.

Comment: the link you provided seems not working. The page keeps loading forever. By the way, if I want to create a custom Bootstap build as you suggested, do you have a set of recommended values (container-sm, container-md, container-lg) for me to start? It seems to me that I also need to adjust screen-xs-min, screen-sm-min, screen-md-min, and screen-lg-min. I am kind of new to Bootstrap. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my link. I've never actually had a need to edit the custom media queries before since the defaults have always worked for me. I would recommend setting the max container-lg to 970 if thats what you want your max width to be. THe site I linked you to lets you see what your changes do to the theme as you make the changes. Hope that was helpful :)

Answer (score 12):

Do you want it responsive? Try this:

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
   }
}
```

This will set container width to 970px for screens wider than 1200px.

Comment: Do you mean `responsive`?

Comment: This is a very good answer and doesn't require to customize with less while retaining full responsiveness.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a custom Bootstrap build, you can wrap your page content in a `container-fixed` DIV and add this CSS after the Bootstrap CSS:

```css
.container-fixed {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 970px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/96043

Comment: I like this simple approach. I tested it and notice that <div class="row"> always has a little extra space on both sides beyond 970px, which makes the browser have a bottom scrollbar.