# Bootstrap max-width over 950px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width

How do I setup the with to say 1200px when my website runs on a regular PC or Mac?

Apparently Bootstrap has 12 columns in it's grid of 60px each plus gutters.
Is there a way to enlarge the column's basic width?

Comment: Are you searching for <body style="width: 1200px"> ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the class .container in your css

```
.container {
   width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: Did you add you css AFTER the bootstrap css in your html?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Body {width:100%;}

@media (min-width: 950px) {
  .container {
    width: 1200px;
   }
}
```

All this means is if your page width is small than `950px` it will change the container to `1200px;`

> Do you want it responsive? 
>   [Answer came from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151458/set-the-page-width-to-max-970px-within-bootstrap-3)